# Bug tracker add remove project member from the project UI help

Tags: website-design, web-app, design

I am working on a bug tracking system. Currently I am working on Add/Edit projects screen.

A user will be assigned to a project, and an admin can add/remove users from the project. So below is what the admin screen will look like.

[image]

Now the part where he adds or remove the project members from the project, I have a lot of confusion on how the UI should be, since I have been working using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) plugin in one of my other project, I tot I could use something like this...

[image]

Need some advice on this and suggestions on what could be a better way to add/remove.

Comment: Do you know all the users' nicknames? I mean what is the principle to add users to a project. What information do you have besides their nicknames? Also you should be able to manage users after project started, probably add someone and delete one.

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko Ya I am storing user's first name, last name and email address. Yes I should allow admin to add/delete users.

Comment: Didn't you think of storing and displaying a person's skills column? And maybe person's involvement in other projects? This helps to make decision whether to pick a person. Also there could be project requirements: e.g. 1 project manager, 2 back-end developers, 1 front-end dev, 1 designer, etc. So I ask again: what is the principle of adding a person to a project? Just based on his name or more complex?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how it is realized in Redmine [(taken from here)](http://wiki.bitnami.com/@api/deki/files/665/=redmine21.png?size=webview). The view shows how the project "Test project" is configured. There are several tabs, for example, in the tab "Information" you can enter the project name and project details. In the tab "Member" you can add members. For this, there is a table listing the current members (here "Admin Admin" is the only member). On the right side, you can search for new members in the box "New member". Existing members are listed below the search box, you can choose on ore more members by selecting the checkboxes next to the names (in the picture, there is only one "Demo User"). You could also decide to use a combobox with names instead. After selecting one ore more users you can add them by clicking on the button "Add".

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I would add a trigger for start typing to add a member. A small empty box next to the last member could help. 
My source for inspiration on this is "seductive interaction design" by Stephen P Anderson.